# Problem updating three tables that are linked to eachother

Tags: php, sql, arrays, database

I am trying to update three tables in my database that are linked to eachother.

My tables are set up like this:

templates

```
id
title
id_company
```

questioncat

```
id
title
ordering
tid (id of templates)
```

questions

```
id
question
catid (id of questioncat)
ordering
```

`templates` contains the name of my question list, `questioncat` contains all categories in my list, and `questions` contains all the questions belonging to a category.

Inserting that data works fine, I do that like this:

First my PHP script gets an array that for example looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => lijsttitle
            [value] => Lijst nieuw
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => category[]
            [value] => cat1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => sortorder
            [value] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => question[]
            [value] => q1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => category[]
            [value] => cat2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => sortorder
            [value] => 2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => question[]
            [value] => q1
        )

)
```

I do a check if the list already exists like this:

```
$check = '
SELECT *
FROM templates
WHERE title = "'.$conn->real_escape_string($title["value"]).'"';
$checkcon = $conn->query($check);
$check = $checkcon->fetch_assoc();
// If there is more than 1 result, update data instead of inserting
if($checkcon->num_rows > 0){

// Else insert data as new list
}else{
    // Insert template title and companyid
    $inserttemplate = '
    INSERT INTO templates (title, id_company) VALUES ("'.$conn->real_escape_string($title["value"]).'","'.$conn->real_escape_string($companyid).'")';
    $inserttemplatecon = $conn->query($inserttemplate);
    $lastinserted = $conn->inserted_id();

    $currCat = '';
    $sortorder = '';

    foreach($arr as $a) {
      $val = $a['value'];
      // handle category
      if($a['name'] == 'category[]') {
        // save cat name
        $currCat = $val;
        // init questions array
        $store[$currCat] = [];
      }else if($a['name'] == 'sortorder') {
            $sortorder = $val;
        $store[$currCat]['sortorder'] = $val;
      }else {
        // add question to question array
        $store[$currCat]['question'][] = $val;
      }
    }

    array_shift($store);
    // $key is de waarde van de categorie, $lijst is een array met alles onder de categorie
    foreach($store as $keycat => $lijst){
        $sortorder = $lijst['sortorder'];

        $insertcats = '
        INSERT INTO questioncat (title, tid, ordering) VALUES ("'.$conn->real_escape_string($keycat).'", "'.$conn->real_escape_string($lastinserted).'", "'.$conn->real_escape_string($sortorder).'")';
        $insertcatscon = $conn->query($insertcats);
        $lastinserted1 = $conn->inserted_id();

        $questionarr = $lijst['question'];

            foreach($questionarr as $q){
                $insertquestions = '
                INSERT INTO questions (question, catid) VALUES ("'.$conn->real_escape_string($q).'", "'.$conn->real_escape_string($lastinserted1).'")';
                $insertquestionscon = $conn->query($insertquestions);
            }
    }

    echo 'Uw lijst is toegevoegd';
}
```

If there are 0 results the list does not exist and is added to my database which works fine, but if there is more than 1 result it means the list does already exist and needs to be updated.

This is where I start getting problems.

Can I update all three tables in one query?

I first tried updating only the category names with the following code inside my if statement (the one where I check if a template list already exists):

```
foreach($arr as $a) {
    $val = $a['value'];
    // handle category
    if($a['name'] == 'category[]') {
        // save cat name
        $currCat = $val;
        // init questions array
        $store[$currCat] = [];
    }else if($a['name'] == 'sortorder') {
        $sortorder = $val;
        $store[$currCat]['sortorder'] = $val;
    }else {
        // add question to question array
        $store[$currCat]['question'][] = $val;
    }

    $updatetemplate = '
    UPDATE questioncat c
    INNER JOIN templates t
    ON c.tid = t.id
    SET t.title = "'.$conn->real_escape_string($title["value"]).'",
    c.title = "'.$conn->real_escape_string($currCat).'",
    c.ordering = "'.$conn->real_escape_string($sortorder).'"
    WHERE t.title = "'.$conn->real_escape_string($getcats['title']).'"
    AND c.id = "'.$conn->real_escape_string($getcats["id"]).'"';
    $updatetemplatecon = $conn->query($updatetemplate);
    echo 'Uw lijst is gewijzigd.';
}
```

But all category titles are the same and the ordering is aswell.

Is it possible to update the three tables in one query? They are basically three levels, Template - Categories beneath template - Questions beneath a category
is it possible and if so, how?

Comment: Which database RDMS are you using and which engine? It's quite important for your case to mention it as the solutions may differ

Comment: @SergeyTelshevsky I am using mysql (SQL) and my database system is phpmyadmin.

Comment: Why you want to do the update in one query? Is there a special reason? Why not update the same way you insert the data (foreach over hirarchy)?

Comment: @SteffenMächtel I am having a difficult time doing that, all categories and questions have the same value when I update like that. Kind of lost overview of my code with all those loops within loops, so I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: @SteffenMächtel Also, I insert to all tables linked to eachother with the last inserted id, for example this line: `$lastinserted1 = $conn->inserted_id();` This does not work for update queries.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to start looking for PL/SQL procedures, they can save you coding and much secure.

**BRIEFING :**

> When an event occurs in the 1st table it
> can execute multiple events on the database, the event could be (ON
> DELETE,ON UPDATE or ON INSERT) with AFTER and BEFORE conditions.

PL/SQL Triggers : [Source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_triggers.htm)

**DEFINITION**

> Triggers are stored programs, which are automatically executed or fired when some events occur.

As for the Syntax it variate depending a little bit depending on which DBMS you are using.
I hope my explanation was good.

Answer (score 0):

To update three tables at the same time you should do it in a single database transaction.

If you have some triggers (ON UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT) on those tables that should be executed, some database engines, like PostgreSQL allows to [defer execution moment of triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html). If the trigger is deferred, it will be executed right after commiting the transaction, and thanks to it you can even update all key types (primary, foreign, unique, complex etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Try update with a single query does not make the process simpler. It would be a very complex update query. And still you need a way to identify somehow the "child" rows (category, question) for every "parent" (templates, category).

**Solution with multiple update/insert queries:**

Every table have a unique id in your example. You could use this id to update specific rows. In your php array (POST/GET?) you have name and value for each item, but no id. Just add "id" additionaly.

If id is empty => INSERT a new row (This item comes not from database)

if id is defined => UPDATE the row with specific id (This item already exists and may have been changed)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => lijsttitle
            [value] => Lijst nieuw
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [name] => category[]
            [value] => cat1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => sortorder
            [value] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 35
            [name] => question[]
            [value] => q1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [name] => category[]
            [value] => cat2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => sortorder
            [value] => 2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [name] => question[]
            [value] => q1
        )

)
```